# i don't understand 'return of if statement' in java

Tags: java, if-statement, return, boolean, boolean-expression

i have a question.....
today i made classes and methods.
and after making a method, i find a error.
that is a "how can i use 'return'?".

what codes are wrong?
i don't find the problem.

```
public boolean locking(){

    if (false)

        System.out.print("Open the door");

        return false;

    else

        System.out.print("Now lock the door");

        return true; //<- how can i express 'return'?

}
```

Comment: That code is syntactically incorrect. You are at least missing some braces.

Comment: If its just a learning code after putting missing braces, its fine. Otherwise your if condition will never be evaluated

Comment: Question: *what codes are wrong?*. Response: *the one in the example*.  Please, post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: Your code always enters the else clause, since if(false) can never be true. We can only guess that you want to check some variable instead of if(false), but you would get much better help if you told us what the code is supposed to do, what happens, and what you expected to happen - it would help a lot if you posted a small and 100% complete example.

Comment: Someone added the missing brackets while editing, which makes the whole question pointless - I removed them again.

Comment: @ldos It won't return anything, because it won't compile, but if it did it would return `false`, not `true.`

Answer (score 4):

This code misses brackets. So the first `if` only refers to the first `System.out`, not the `return`.

Try the following:

```
public boolean locking() {
    if (false) {
        System.out.print("Open the door");
        return false;
    } else {
        System.out.print("Now lock the door");
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Keep in mind that the defined if-condition in the above code is absolutely pointless. So make sure you're always comparing something, else you'll always get the same result.

It's also important to know that using a return-statement will exit the method, this means that any code below the `return` will not be executed. This allows you to leave out the `else` part of the if-statement. Because when the condition is met the first return will be executed and leave the method, when it's not met the code continues to the *only other possibility*. This makes the code a little lighter, but be warned when using multiple if statements.

```
public boolean locking() {
    if (false) {
        System.out.print("Open the door");
        return false;
    }

    System.out.print("Now lock the door");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You fixed the syntax a little but the first if condition is absolutely pointless... So the OP should definitely keep that in mind. Also when using returns based only one condition, there is no need to define an `else`, the `return` will exit the method and not execute any code below it.

Comment: That's right. The question was not very specific: "i find a error". I fixed it so that the code wouldn't produce a compile error thinking this would help the OP learning :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use some statements like (if, for ,...) you should use brackets if you want to use multiple statements in (if) statement.

this is wrong(the return value doesn't depend (if) statement):

```
if (false)
    System.out.print("Open the door");
    return false;
```

but this is true(when you use brackets):

```
if (false)
{
    System.out.print("Open the door");
    return false;
}
```

Just use brackets `{ your code }` after `if`.